# Install pandas in debian10 on a different python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, debian

I have a device with python3.7 preinstalled, in which i have installed also python3.9. I managed to change the version I am using of python3 and now the command "python3" followed by the .py file runs with python3.9.

The problem is I tried installing pandas with pip3 but it does not work (it didn't work even in the preinstalled python3.7), so I found that in debian you can install package, for example in this case pandas, using "sudo apt-get install python3-pandas" but this command keeps installing pandas in python3.7 and not in python3.9 even if now "python3" refers to python3.9.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and has a solution?

Comment: It would be good, if you clarify your actual question. Because this is about a very specific problem with pandas and your machine and not a generic problem, according to your comment below.

Also mention the complete error message. That will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ok I will publish the error that it provides me with pip, the other command (sudo apt-get install python3-pandas) just directly install to python3.7 (which is the preinstalled version) so it does not give me an error but simply install pandas in the wrong python version

Answer (score 0):

`python3.9 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already tried this and every command with pip inside has some problems in installing pandas (also in python3.7). The only thing that seems to work is that command "sudo apt-get install python3-pandas" but it keeps referring to python3.7 and not 3.9

Comment: What is the error message when you do the pip install?

Comment: @LucaM So you should now solve the problem encountered in `python3.9 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Sadly it is a problem of this device that pandas does not work with pip and "sudo apt-get install python3-pandas" has to be used but i want it to refer to python3.9 and not the preinstalled 3.7

Comment: My best guess is how to solve this is , you should look up the installation paths for both python versions and also the installation path for pandas. See how the pandas library is provided to python3.7 and then replicate this to the python 3.9 version. Probably a symlink from pandas to the python site-packages could solve it.

Comment: "See how the pandas library is provided to python3.7 and then replicate this to the python 3.9 version" this is what I am trying to figure out. If with your last sentence you mean dowloading the tar.gz and installing it from there I have altready tried it and it does not work

Comment: I mean, you could create a ymlink from the pandas installation into the site-packages path of your python3.9 installation. So python3.9 will find the pandas package, which you installed via apt-get

Comment: I'm sorry since i do not know how to do it can you send me a link where it is explained how to do it? I am sorry to disrurb you

Answer (score 0):

## Venv

You could use a virtual environment (venv) for installing dependencies.
This venv could be project specific or global.

Run `python3 -m venv .venv` in your project folder to create a `.venv` folder, which holds the venv configuration.

Run `source .venv/bin/activate` to activate the venv. This will link `pip3` from your python 3.9 version to the `pip` command.

Now you can do `pip install pandas` to install the pandas dependency into the venv.

## Conda

Another solution would be to use **Anaconda** or **Miniconda**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

> ```
>  conda create -n name_of_my_env python
> ```
>
> This will create a minimal environment with only Python installed in
> it.
>
> To put your self inside this environment run:
>
> ```
>  source activate name_of_my_env
> ```
>
> On Windows the command is:
>
> ```
>  activate name_of_my_env
> ```
>
> The final step required is to install pandas. This can be done with
> the following command:
>
> ```
>  conda install pandas
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but sadly on this device everything that uses pip does not work with pandas. As I stated in the question the only thing that works is that command "sudo apt-get install python3-pandas" but it keeps referring to the python3.7 version